# Fluent NHibernate 3 uniquekey  custom constraint name

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, constraints, unique-key

I am trying to give a custom Unique Constraint Name as follows:

```
Map(x => x.Name).UniqueKey("MY_CONSTRAINT_NAME").Column("FUNCTION_NAME");
```

The Field is mapped with a unique constraint but the constraint name is self-managed and doesn't take the name I chose ("MY_CONSTRAINT_NAME")
Is this a BUG or am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: Are you deleting the schema each time.  I've seen issues before where I needed to delete the schema for changes like that to take effect.  So basically drop the database and recreate it via exporting the schema.

Comment: I always drop the database manually and then i recreate the schema but i cant see any change

Answer (score 2):

NHibernate itself does not allow you to supply a name for the unique key.  https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1955